# Android Wear: Google Play services out of date. Requires x but found y

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, wear-os

I have an Android Wear app that I'm trying to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio. It's working (more or less) on my LG G Watch, but when run on my Moto 360 I get the following message in logcat:

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 6111000 but found 5091534
```

followed immediately by `Connection to Google API client has failed`. Running on the emulator gives a similar message:

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 6111500 but found 5077534
```

It strikes me as odd that the `Requires` version is slightly different in each case, but there you are.

I've been through the similar questions here on SO, and the answers usually boil down to ensuring that the module's Gradle dependencies are using `play-services-wearable` rather than just `play-services`. I've checked this and it appears to be correct; here's the relevant section from my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':wearableCommon')
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

Note that `wearableCommon` is a library of my own, containing code I'm using in several wearable projects, and it doesn't use GMS.

I'm particularly bothered by the fact that this works on one device but not another. If I didn't have the 360 in-house, I might well have released this code after testing it on my G Watch. I would have then been in the position of trying to debug this in the wild, while simultaneously doing damage control for hundreds of angry 360 owners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Easiest "fix":**

Set your `play-services-wearable` to specifically look for 5.0.77

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:5.0.77'`

**More info:**

https://plus.google.com/u/0/101581283591300788111/posts/5bHfmjtvQ6R

I literally had this exact same problem. Wayne is trying to help me out with it. Join the discussion if you like.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. This problem happened because of the mismatch of android versions in wear(running lollipop) and my phone(running kitkat).

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Google Play Services was rolled out to Android Wear devices recently. The latest SDK update for play-services-wearable requires that your wearable is updated, which is shown in the error message that you report. Make sure you have the latest companion app installed on your phone, and it will install the update to your wearable as well. Make sure that you have your wearable paired with your phone, otherwise it will not be able to update the wearable!

If you have your wearable paired with your phone, these things will automatically update and there should be not be a problem.

I would not recommend hard coding your build.gradle to 5.0.77, because then you will never update to use the new APIs for Play Services.

Comment: With all due respect, this isn't a solution for a production app. The problem isn't specifically that *my* watch (or emulator - WTF) has outdated software, it's that this app will be distributed to thousands of users. And in the real world, not every user has the latest version of all software at all times. It's not acceptable for an app that someone's paid for to simply not work when their GMS hasn't yet synced. At best, I'd have to put in code to check that the GMS version was OK - and that wouldn't actually fix it, just make it fail less opaquely.

Comment: I understand your concern here, but in order to get the app onto a user's watch, it will be delivered via the Play Store and the companion app. The companion app containing the latest version of Google Play Services will also be updated at the same time, and so there will be no problem. So this problem should not affect regular users downloading via the Play Store, and not installing apps manually via ADB.

Comment: You can also fix the build.gradle version to something like 5.0+ or 5.0.77 if you really want to stick with a specific known version. But then you will miss out on any bug fixes that are released. But you do have the ability to decide what is acceptable to you here.